# AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

Tags: python, django

Version numbers are Django 1.6, Python 3.3.2 and Mac OS X 10.9

I create an app with this command

```
 python3 manage.py startapp lists
```

Then in my lists/tests.py file I put this code

```
from django.test import TestCase

class SmokeTest(TestCase):

 def test_bad_maths(self):
    self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 3)
```

then I run this command from the app root folder

```
python3 manage.py test
```

and this is the stack trace that comes back, it's not working correctly

```
    E

         ======================================================================
ERROR: test_bad_maths (lists.tests.SmokeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 111, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 85, in get_connection_params
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 653, in supports_transactions
    self.connection.enter_transaction_management()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 288, in enter_transaction_management
    if managed == self.get_autocommit():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in get_autocommit
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 86, in __exit__
    db_exc_type = getattr(self.wrapper.Database, dj_exc_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 111, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 85, in get_connection_params
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 178, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 749, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 861, in _fixture_setup
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 848, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 848, in <genexpr>
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 664, in supports_transactions
    self.connection.leave_transaction_management()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 317, in leave_transaction_management
    if managed == self.get_autocommit():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in get_autocommit
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 86, in __exit__
    db_exc_type = getattr(self.wrapper.Database, dj_exc_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.031s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Have done a "startproject" before "startapp" ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Have you done a "startproject" before "startapp" ? What is `test_basic_addition`? It's not in your code. Shouldn't you test the specific app (`python3 manage.py test lists`) ?

Comment: yeah I did startproject before startapp, and tried the command you gave me, the same stacktrace comes back except with the error header ERROR: test_bad_maths (lists.tests.SmokeTest) instead, I don't know how that was there, I fixed it now, I have tried uninstalling django, completely making sure there was no other versions on my mac, then reinstalling it and same errors, also tried setting up a virtualenv environment with a fresh django and same stacktrace comes back, im stumped at what it could be, I think it wants some database initialized but it shouldn't need one for a simple test

Comment: also have confirmed im using django 1.6

Comment: Are you using the default settings.py with database `django.db.backends.sqlite3` ? I have really the same config (OS X 10.9.5). I did: `brew install python3` which installed me python3 its depdencies (including sqlite3), then I did `pip3 install virtualenv`, I created a virtualenv and installed django==1.6, copied over your unit tests and it works for me. It's like you were using a incorrect settings.py. Can you show your complete settings.py ?

Comment: yeah that was the problem I was using a Django 1.5 settings.py which didn't default to sqlite3

Comment: Should I create a complete answer or would you like to do it yourself, so it can be marked as answered?

Comment: Ok. I created a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exact the same environment:
 * Mac OS X 10.9
 * Python 3.3.2
 * Django 1.6

I have virtualenv 1.10.1 installed and create one, install django and create the project and app:

```
virtualenv-3.3 tt
cd tt
. bin/activate
pip install django==1.6
django-admin.py startproject myproj
cd myproj
chmod +x manage.py
./manage.py startapp lists
```

Now I pasted your code into lists/test.py and run the test with the default settings.py (database sqlite3, etc.)

```
./manage.py test
```

and got the right results:

Creating test database for alias 'default'...

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_bad_maths (lists.tests.SmokeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erevilla/tt/myproj/lists/tests.py", line 6, in test_bad_maths
    self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 3)
AssertionError: 2 != 3

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I can't reproduce your problem. Please check:

- settings.py (what database are you using)
- manage.py (for incorrect version)
- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined